# I'm making a django webapp and I keep getting pk errors

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

I keep getting this error even after migrating, making migrations, importing get_object functions,

```
Page not found (404)
No storage found matching the query
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/change-info/1
Raised by:  base.views.UpdateInfo
Using the URLconf defined in mywallet.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
[name='list']
descript/<int:pk>/ [name='descript']
create-bank/ [name='create-bank']
change-info/<int:pk> [name='change-info']
The current path, change-info/1, matched the last one.

You’re seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

This is my views.py code

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from .models import Storage
# Create your views here.


class Listings(ListView):
    model = Storage
    context_object_name = 'banks'

class Information(DetailView):
    model = Storage
    template_name = 'base/storage_detail.html'
   

class NewBank(CreateView):
    model = Storage
    fields = '__all__'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('list')


class UpdateInfo(UpdateView):
    model = Storage
    fields = '__all__'
    reverse_lazy('list')
```

my urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import Listings, Information, NewBank, UpdateInfo

urlpatterns = [
    path('', Listings.as_view(), name= 'list'),
    path('descript/<int:pk>/', Information.as_view(), name='descript'),
    path('create-bank/', NewBank.as_view(), name='create-bank'),
    path('change-info/<int:pk>', UpdateInfo.as_view(), name='change-info')
]
```

my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class Storage(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    bank_name = models.CharField(max_length=80, null=True, blank=True)
    account_number = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.bank_name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created']
```

The django application's urls.py

```
"""mywallet URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include('base.urls')),
]
```

I think I've tried everything
What else can I do almost all the answers I've seen to this havent worked for me and the 404 page shows when I use details and update
But it works for the rest
is there something I put in there that is wrong or do i need to replace a class-based function

Can someone help me

Comment: django expects you send a pk in request, add sample data that you are sending .

Comment: Sorry what could you mean by that, what sample data, I already input data using my admin platform

Comment: Can you share your html file, the one where your UpdateView?

Comment: <h1>
    My Bank Details
</h1>
<a href="{% url 'create-bank' %}"> Add New Bank</a>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Bank Name</th>
        <th>Account Number</th>
    </tr>
    {% for bankd in banks%}
    <tr>
        <td>
            {{ bankd.bank_name}}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ bankd.account_number}}
        </td>
        <td><a href="{% url 'descript' bank.id%}">Edit Information</a></td>
        <td><a href="{% url 'delete-info' bank.id%}">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
    {%endfor%}
 </table>

Comment: put this HTML In question - it will be more readable, and more peopel will see it - so more people can help you.

Comment: did you run in console/terminla? It may show more useful information about problem.

Comment: Have you made a form for the update view?

Comment: add / slash to end of your url, maybe it's because of that